# I have multiple accounts

Tags: gmail

I have multiple accounts because I kept trying to start all over. Sometimes I will friend people and they say comments that are inappropriate. And I have forgotten the passwords to those accounts. How would I locate them and close them?

Answer (score 0):

When you try and login to your Gmail account there will be a 'Forgot Password' button. You should be able to recover your password through either text verification if you have entered your phone number, or through security questions, or through a second recovery email which you would have connected to the account when you set it up.

Once you have accessed the password you can close it using [these steps.](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/61177?hl=en)